# SQL Server : special calculation for value in a view

Tags: sql-server, view, case, partition

I would like to calculate the column (calculated) as below:

[image]

The `Calculated` value is twice the `Value`, as long as there is not a lower value that has a `Calculated` value that is higher than `Value`, otherwise it should be zero.

Basically the column `Calculated` should have as its MAX a value that would be at least half the size of all values of its category (`Column1`).

I have a view in a SQL Server database, that means for me that I can not use `ORDER BY`.

My example values:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table2020 
(
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 VARCHAR(1),
    Value INT
)
```

I populate it like:

```
INSERT INTO test_table2020 
VALUES  (1, 'A', 10), (1, 'A', 12),
        (1, 'A', 22), (1, 'A', 23),
        (1, 'A', 13), (1, 'A', 24),
        (2, 'B', 15), (3, 'C', 16),
        (3, 'C', 28), (3, 'C', 31),
        (4, 'D', 9) , (4, 'D', 9)
```

I think that I from here would be able to get the max(calculated) for every different Column1.

I do not really have any idea what to do, that will work in the case with a few rows.

This will show the calculated values without the zeros:

```
SELECT *, value * 2 AS Calculated FROM test_table2020
```

The thing is for calculating what value stuff should be uppgraded to without overdoing it.

Comment: Side note: when inserting **numerical** values - you should **avoid** putting those into single quotes - just use `VALUES  (1, 'A', 10), (1, 'A', 12),` - only use single quotes around **string** or **date/time** values - not numbers

Comment: I have updated it now, thanks!

Comment: The **third value** of each tuple also is an `INT` which also should not be in single quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window functions in concert with a CASE will help here

EDIT:  Not clear if `Column2` should be embedded in the `partition`  the pattern is a little ambiguous.

**Example**

```
Select *
       ,Calculated =  case when (Value*1.5<max(Value) over (partition by column1) 
                                 and  sum(1) over (partition by column1) > 1 )
                                 or ( avg(value) over (partition by column1) = value   )
                           then Value * 2
                           else 0 end
 From  test_table2020
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks much better than I could do. But I have added some values for clarification. There is not only one value that shoud be zero, but many of them as longe as there is some value half its size. Then I added a duplicate as well. I will upgrade the question. Thanks anyway it is a good start.

Comment: Yes column2 is a kind of description column that has text.

Comment: @MichaelLarsson Lost internet for a bit.  Just required a little tweak in the logic.

Comment: I think it worked, thanks. I been working with your first answer and made some progress: Select *
       ,Calculated =  case when (Value*1.5<max(Value) over (partition by column1) 
                                 and  sum(1) over (partition by column1) > 1 )
                                 or ( avg(value) over (partition by column1) = value   )
                           then Value * 2
                           else 0 end
 From  test_table2020

Comment: @MichaelLarsson  Everyone needs a nudge from time to time.   Always fun when you can solve your issue.

Comment: It works excactly as my sugestion, thanks! I will mark your answer as a solution.

Comment: @MichaelLarsson Always happy to help